# Android: why does FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT exhibit such behaviour?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

I have been working with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` to manage the Activity stack but I have realized that this flag has a diferent behaviour in diferent devices. Imagine I have in the stack these activities: **A->B->C->D** and from D I open activity B using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag, so the new stack state is **A->C->D->B**. If I press the back button from B what you expect to see is D and after C and finally A. It works as expected in all phones I have tested, but the point is that it works in the same way only in some tablets because in others the application is closed when I press the back button. In the Nexus 10 when I open activity B from D and I press the back button the application is closed and if I reopen it what I have is the activities that were in the stack previosly (**A->C->D**).

Someone has any idea about what is happening this? It seems that the internal implementation is dferent in diferent Android versions :$

Comment: If the app is closing then it is probably crashing for a different reason. Have you looked at the logcat on Nexus 10 when you press BACK and the app closes?

Comment: The app is not crashing, what I said is the app is closed but not because a crash, just closed.